# importing a class of functions header

Tags: ios, methods, import

I am re-factoring my code to make it more manageable I want to create a class that contains functions that I can load in to other classes.

I have created a class called functions, imported funtions.h into the .h of my ViewController Class, the functions .m to the ViewController.m but the complier does not recognise the method hasInternetconnection when is called and crashes.

I am not completely lost as to why I cannot call this method in this class

here is my code, and I have had a good look through s/o and google and I still can't see what I am doing wrong

Functions.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Functions : NSObject


-(BOOL)hasInternetConection;
@end
```

Functions.m

```
#import "Functions.h"

@implementation Functions



-(BOOL)hasInternetConection{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *res=nil;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&res error:NULL];
    if (res!=nil) {
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;}

}

@end
```

HomeViewController.h

```
...
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "multiShotViewController.h"
#import "Functions.h"
...
```

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {

```
UIGlossyButton *b;
```

HomeViewController.m

```
...
#import "detailsViewController.h"
#import "Functions.h"
#define  Kwelome @"welcomeread"


@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@class Functions;
@implementation HomeViewController
@synthesize tripName;
@synthesize databasePath, deathtrail;
@synthesize lampingbtn,deerstalkingbtn,boundarybtn, optionsbtn,shootingbtn;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Home";
        UIColor *backg=[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgcamo.png"]];
        self.view.backgroundColor=backg;
        [backg release];
    }
    return self;
}
...
```

Comment: Where are you calling `-(BOOL)hasInternetConection` in your HomeViewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @class Functions; is not required at least. You are importing header files already so you don't have redeclare it.

Where are you caling those methods ? Are you sure you call them on instance of that class ?

I suspect a problem that you're trying to do

```
[Functions hasInternetConection]
```

instead of

```
Functions * func = [[Functions alloc] init];
[func hasInternetConection];
[func release];
```

If you do it like in first example than change declaration to "+" instead of "-" in your function - so it can be used as static method.

Comment: many thanks Grzegorz i had got a good few things mixed up there, all working now cheers buddy